# CSS not being read for image layout

Tags: html, css

I'm new to both CSS & HTML use. I added to our CSS page referencing the `logo` class with the following code:

```
logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 0%;
}
```

That refers to the following HTML class:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/images/Catlogo.jpg" 
     alt="Caterpillar logo" width="115" height="50" class="logo">
```

including the whole parent container:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">

    <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/images/Catlogo.jpg" alt="Caterpillar logo" 
        width="115" height="50" class="logo">

    <a class="navbar-brand mr-1" href="pservlet">[Offer To Sell] Grief Reconciliation</a>

    <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm text-white order-1 order-sm-0"
        id="sidebarToggle" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
```

However, the picture in the navbar does not change despite having the CSS reference. Essentially I am simply trying to anchor the image (Refer to the screenshot below)
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is in the parent container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In css, class references should be marked with a leading period, `.logo`. You will need to modify your css class as below

```
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 0%;
}

<img src="Catlogo.jpg" alt="Caterpillar logo" width="115" height="50" class="logo">
```